# Qt code sequence in multithread. Is this possible?

Tags: multithreading, qt, qthread

This is objectA which subclass QThread

```
void run()
{
    while (continue)
        emit query();
}

void work(int input, bool workdone)
{
     // work hard here
     if (workdone) { continue = false; }
}
```

This is some code in main object

```
{
    ObjectA A* = new ObjectA(this);
    connect(A, SIGNAL(query()), this, SLOT(handleQuery()));
    objectA.start();
}

void handleQuery()
{
    A.work(interger, allJobDONE);
}
```

OK, I don't know how to name the question. Basically, it is just "will this code work?" If yes, how would be the code sequence?

Let me explain my question. ObjectA is a thread. It is going to query information from time to time by emitting a query signal. When the query signal is grubbed by the main code, the main code decide whether there is job so as to send the job to ObjectA by calling `work()` function.
If this code works, both the `run()` and the `work()` function in the same object work at the same time. Is this possible?

Comment: A.work() will run in the (main?) thread, is that really what you're intended? If yes, then work() shouldn't be in ObjectA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few problems:

- the function `ObjectA::run()` blocks the event loop of the thread;
- `A.work()` is called from the wrong thread;
- it is needed to think about proper deletion of `A`.

Instead of blocking `while` loop in `run()` it is better to use timer. However, in that case the thread event loop should be executed (that it done in the default implementation of `QThread::run()`. So some other member slot should be used for that task to start, for example:

```
void ObjectA::doLoop()
{
    emit query();
    QTimer::singleShot(0, this, SLOT(doLoop()));
}
```

That function should be called when the thread is started, for example it can be done by connection in `ObjectA` constructor:

```
connect(this, SIGNAL(started()), this, SLOT(doLoop()));
```

Even better to keep private pointer `QTimer*` to be able to stop that timer from `work()` or to have some other control. Note that in that case `QTimer` object should be in the same thread as `ObjectA`.

Normally the `ObjectA::work()` function should be triggerd by some signal from `handleQuery()`. The event loop of `ObjectA` will catch that signal and the `work()` will be started in `ObjectA` thread.