# Qthread multithread unexpect result

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I want to achieve several things with my code:

1. Two threads, printing "foo" and "bar" 100 times to console simultaneously. Order doesn't matter.
2. The object which created the threads needs to get a signal when they finish. In real life, this signal will carry the thread's result, and the creator needs to wait for this result.

This is the code I made for this example:

#### main.cpp

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "controller.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    Controller controller;
    return a.exec();
}
```

#### controller.h

```
#ifndef CONTROLLER_H
#define CONTROLLER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QThread>
#include <QEventLoop>
#include <QTimer>

#include "textwriter.h"

class Controller: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Controller(QObject* parent = 0);

signals:
    void startWrite();

public slots:
    void catchFinish();
};

#endif // CONTROLLER_H
```

#### controller.cpp

```
#include "controller.h"

Controller::Controller(QObject* parent):QObject(parent)
{
    // QThread
    QThread threadA;
    QThread threadB;
    // Worker that will send to the thread
    textWriter workerA("foo");
    textWriter workerB("bar");

    // Send the worker to the thread
    workerA.moveToThread(&threadA);
    workerB.moveToThread(&threadB);

    // I will emit startWrite() later to begin all the job
    connect(this, &Controller::startWrite, &workerA, &textWriter::write);
    connect(this, &Controller::startWrite, &workerB, &textWriter::write);

    // The worket will send back finish signal to me
    connect(&workerA, &textWriter::finish, this, &Controller::catchFinish);
    connect(&workerB, &textWriter::finish, this, &Controller::catchFinish);
    // Also kill the thread as well
    connect(&workerA, &textWriter::finish, &threadA, &QThread::quit);
    connect(&workerB, &textWriter::finish, &threadB, &QThread::quit);

    // If the thread was killed, let the system delete it
    connect(&threadA, &QThread::finished, &threadA, &QThread::deleteLater);
    connect(&threadB, &QThread::finished, &threadB, &QThread::deleteLater);


    // I start the thread here
    emit startWrite();

    QEventLoop eventloopA;
    connect(&workerA, &textWriter::finish, &eventloopA, &QEventLoop::quit);
    QEventLoop eventloopB;
    connect(&workerB, &textWriter::finish, &eventloopB, &QEventLoop::quit);

    threadA.start();
    threadB.start();
    eventloopA.exec();
    eventloopB.exec();
}

void Controller::catchFinish()
{
    qDebug() << "finish signal catched";
}
```

#### textwriter.h

```
#ifndef TEXTWRITER_H
#define TEXTWRITER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QThread>
#include <QDebug>

class textWriter : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QString text;
public:
    textWriter(QString text, QObject *parent = 0);
public slots:
    void write();

signals:
    void finish();
};

#endif // TEXTWRITER_H
```

#### textwriter.cpp

```
#include "textwriter.h"

textWriter::textWriter(QString text,QObject* parent):QObject(parent)
{
    this->text = text;
}

void textWriter::write()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    {
        qDebug() << "Thread Number:\t"
                 << QThread::currentThreadId()
                 << "\tCount: "
                 << i
                 << "\t"
                 << text;
    }
    emit finish();
    qDebug() << "finish() signal emitted";
}
```

However I got all types of result.
I want to know the reason of those result.

1. Both threads work as expected. They do things in turn and complete.
   Reason: No reason. This is the desired operation.
2. One thread go from 0 to 99 first and the second thread start after. Program complete.
   Reason: It is up to the cpu scheduler.
3. Both threads start at the same time. They do their job. However when the first thread finishes, the program terminates. The last print out of the second thread is still at count = 38.
   Reason: ?
4. Both threads do their job. But there is a `Error: double free or corruption` in the console.
   Reason: ?
5. QThread destroy when it is running printed.
   Reason: ? Seems likely to be same cause to problem 3.

### Latest Update and Suggestion:

I put some comment here to help anybody who have difficulties understanding `QThread` like me. This is contributed by people who help me at these questions [main-thread-cannot-get-signal-form-worker-thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33716719/main-thread-cannot-get-signal-form-worker-thread), [qt-code-sequence-in-multitread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33705975/qt-code-sequence-in-multitread) and the current post. Also, this [article](https://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/) is a very good read.

First you need to create an Object which inherit `QObject`. This object is where the multithread job is to run. As mentioned in the [article](https://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/), the object constructor should not contain anything create in the heap using `new`. The constructor object is best to be as simple as possible because jobs are not supposed to be done at the constructor. Instead, all jobs should put in the slot of this object.

It is also very important to create `finish()` signal. This signal should be emit at the end of every job function in order to tell the thread controller it has finished its job. It is also a good way to put the result of your job inside the finish signal like this `finish(int, QString,.......)`

This is how the worker object looks like:

```
class Object : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Object(QObject *parent = 0);

// All multi thread works should create in term of slot
public slots:
    void job1();
    void job2();
    void job3();
    void job4();

signals:
    void finish();
    void finish(int result);
};
```

To start with, we create this Object and a `QThread` Object. Be careful in how the `QThread` object is created, in the heap or on the stack. It will lead to two different approaches to end the thread.

```
QThread stackThread;
Object workerStack;
QThread* heapThread = new Qthread;
Object workerHeap;
```

After creating the thread and worker object, just move the worker to the thread. There is no magic here.

```
workerStack.moveToThread(&stackThread);
workerHeap.moveToThread(heapThread);
```

Then connect a signal so that when `QThread::start` is invoked, the object starts to work:

```
connect(&stackThread, &QThread::started, &workerStack, &Object::job1);
connect(heapThread, &QThread::started, &workerHeap, &Object::job2);
```

You can just use the `finish()` signal for stopping the thread.

```
connect(&workerStack, &Object::finish, &stackThread, &QThread::quit);
connect(&workerHeap, &Object::finish, heapThread, &QThread::quit);
```

You can need one more signal-slot so that the thread created in the heap can delete itself when it is finished. This is NOT needed for the thread created in the stack.

```
connect(&workerHeap, &Object::finish, heapThread, &QThread::deleteLater);
```

If your `finish()` signal contains return result, you may convey your result like this.

```
connect(&workerStack, &Object::finish, this, &THISSCOPE::catchFinish);
```

If you need to wait for the thread result to continue your program, you can use `QEventLoop`. Please don't use the `QThread::wait` function that was not supposed to do this job. The `wait` function simply block the current eventloop so that you can never catch the `finish` signal.

Although using `QEventLoop` can allow you to receive `finish` signal, it is not a good design. There are ways to avoid it, but I would not elaborate here. I just use to `QEventLoop` to demonstrate how the current scope can receive signal. Here is the code:

```
QEventLoop eventloop;
connect(&workerStack, &Object::finish, &eventloop, &QEventLoop::quit);
```

Now, we can start the thread after all slot-slot created:

```
threadStack.start();
threadHeap.start();
```

Start the eventloop if you need to wait for the result:

```
eventloop.exec();
```

When the thread finishes, the thread created in the heap should emit the `finish` signal and delete itself (because you connected to its `deleteLater` slot). However, the thread created on the stack is a bit tricky. If your main code goes out of scope here, you may get an error "QThread is destroyed when it is running". It is because the main code go a bit faster than the `QThread::quit`. So, you need to put a `QThread::wait` here. The real usage of the `wait` function is to wait the thread to quit after the job finish. **IT IS NOT FOR WAITING THE JOB TO FINISH**. So finally, we add this:

```
threadStack.wait();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too many bugs...

Few more remarks in addition to the previous Antwane's answer.

- It is a bad idea to call `delete` for objects allocated on stack. The objects `threadA` and `threadB` are on stack of the `Controller` constructor. They are automatically deleted when the constructor is finished and also they are deleted second time due to `deleteLater()`.
- The main event loop is blocked while `eventloopA` and `eventloopB` are running. So, the `Controller` object cannot receive any signal before both threads are not finished. It is not needed to block the `Controler` constructor. I guess that the idea to block it comes from the problem that the thread objects are destroyed. However, the thread objects could be created using `new` to avoid that problem.
- In general it is not good to delete a thread by its `finished` signal. In general it is possible that the application is closed before calling `QThread::quit()` and before the `QThread::finished()` signal is emitted.

See the `Controler` example in `QThread` [Detailed Description](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#details). `QThread` can be deleted in other even loop (not its own). However, even when the main even loop (main thread) catches the thread `QThread::finished()` signal that `QThread` still may be busy. To make sure that the thread is really done before its deletion there is the function `QThread::wait()`.

Comment: "It is a bad idea to call delete for objects allocated on stack." Thanks. I use the `deleteLater` in a wrong way.

Comment: The main event loop is blocked while eventloopA and eventloopA are running. I need this because in my real program, I need to wait for the results from the thread. The eventloop can achieve this. But after reading other articles, I find out that it is a good design to wait for result like this, at the same time blocking the constructor.

Comment: @tom It must be strange articles. If you ineeded want to block `Controler` constructor you can use `threadA.wait(); threadB.wait();` instead of creation new `eventloopA` and `eventloopB`. In that way the constructor will be blocked until `threadA` and `threadB` are finished. Then the thread can be safely destroyed by leaving the ctor block. `QEventLoop` cannot guaranty this, since threads are still activte when the signals `textWriter::finish` are received. `deleteLater` is not needed at all in that case.

Comment: @tom If you indeed do not want to use event mechanism for handling worker finished status (it does not work while the main thread is blocked) the blocking result can be achived with `QFutureSynchronizer` http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfuturesynchronizer.html#details without many `QThread` insteances. So, the problem can be solved either using `QThread` without blocking any event loop or using `QFutureSynchronizer` for blocking.

Comment: @tom The answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33716719/main-thread-cannot-get-signal-form-worker-thread means that it is needed to have at least one event loop in the main thread (`QCoreApplication` already has such loop), but this event loop should not be used for blocking operations.

Comment: Indeed the eventloop blocks the constructor but you can apply signal to quit the eventloop. Meanwhile, your thread can emit the result and be destroyed in whatever way. On the contrary thread.wait() cannot help the main thread to accept result. Your main thread cannot accept signal while the wait eventloop is blocking. You need to end the wait eventloop before you can accept signal. Your  worker thread now is trying to emit the result to the main thread while the main thread is waiting for the worker thread top finish. I think this is the so called deadlock.

Comment: After stuck on the qthread for long time. I got a good idea.  Qthread and worker thread is created and they are connected by signal and slot.  After the thread::start is called, the main scope should end immediately. What we should do is to emit signal when the thread is finished. Then, the main thread catch the signal to continue.

Answer (score 1):

The different behaviors and errors you described are pretty difficult to debug. But you will probably see the errors disappear and the behaviors be more consistent when the creation, destruction, start and end of your threads will be correctly implemented.

Some hints:

- You don't need to initialize QEventLoop instances. The default QThread implementation already have an eventLoop (read [QThread::run()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qthread.html#run) and [QThread::exec()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qthread.html#exec))
- The proper way to start your thread is to call [QThread::start()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qthread.html#start). If you connect [QThread::started()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qthread.html#started) to Controller::startWrite() and delete `emit startWrite();`, the program will do the same job.

From your example, you have (at least) 2 solutions to improve the implementation:

1. Use you textWriter class as it. In that case, you can create a QThread and a textWriter, move the textWriter instance to QThread using moveToThread, connect QThread::started to textWriter::write and textWriter::finish to QThread::quit and finally start the thread using QThread::start()
2. The other solution is to modify textWriter. You can turn textWriter into a child of QRunnable and rename textWriter::write into [run()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qrunnable.html#run). Then use a QThreadPool to start the execution.

In any case, I suggest you to read a summary of [multithreading technologies in Qt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-technologies.html) that will probably help you to find the solution that match your specific case !

Good luck ;)

Comment: I initialize QEventLoop because I need to wait for the signal come from the textWriter. Is there any alternative way a can pause the controller and wait for the signal?

Comment: I discover the `connect(&threadB, &QThread::finished, &threadB, &QThread::deleteLater);` contribute to the unstability for Error: double free or corruption

Comment: I use your suggestion `connect(&threadA, &QThread::started, &workerA, &textWriter::write);` I don't know whether these help.

Comment: After applying the above two changes, the multi thread run quite stable. At least it can run till the end, emit signal and the controller can get the signal.

Comment: But the `QThread::Destroy while thread is running` is still a issue. It won't affect the result. It appears after threads finished. Just trying to figure out the reason...........